ITMS-90035: Invalid Signature: Expo
I have created an Expo build and encountered an 'Invalid Signature' issue upon submission to the App Store. Despite numerous attempts to find solutions on StackOverflow, all responses were primarily for React Native CLI and not specifically for Expo.

ITMS-90035: Invalid Signature - The binary with bundle identifier com.myclique.mycliqueapp at path “MyClique.app” contains an invalid signature. Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level). If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose “Clean All” in Xcode, delete the “build” directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target.

Here is the screen short

